# why this function returns null?

Tags: c

This code finds the next word in the string.

**For example**

given an input of `"  my cake"` the function should return `"my cake"`. as the expected output

*If I use `return` then the output is (null), but I use `printf` then the code works*

I would like to know how to get the expected output using return.

```
       #include <stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
        char* str[1000]; 
        printf("enter:");
        fgets(str,1000,stdin);

        printf("%s",find_word_start(str));
        }



        char* find_word_start(char* str){
                char* result[1000];
                int c = 0, d = 0;
                while(str[c] ==' ') { 
                    c++; 
                }
                while(str[c] != '\0'){ 
                    result[d++] = str[c++];

                    if(str[c]==' ') {
                    result[d++] = str[c++]; 
                } 
                while(str[c]==' ') { // 
                    c++; 
                } 
            }
            result[d] = '\0';

            //print or return char?
            return result;
    }
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `char result[1000]` instead of `char *result[1000]`? Also - `result` is an automatic variable defined on the stack. Returning it from a subroutine is a classic mistake. Suggest: define `result` as `char *`, allocate memory for it dynamically, and return that. Caller is the responsible for cleaning up the allocated memory.

Comment: You're returning pointer to stack value. Does this even compile?

Comment: @geckos: that would depend very much on the OS, compiler, and compiler options being used.

Comment: @BobJarvis I tried `char result[1000]` and still returns null, I do not know how to allocate memory dinamically, I am new to c language. I tried `char* result;` instead of `char* result[1000]` and it works know even though I do not understand why.

Comment: `result` is an array of automatic storage duration, so ceases to exist as far as the program is concerned when the function returns.    Using it as a return value, and using that return value in the caller, causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line allocates memory space in the stack but after the function ends everything is gone:

```
char result[1000];
```

You need to allocate memory in the heap like that:

```
char *result = malloc(sizeof(char) *1000);
```

Note: don't forget to free that memory space by `free` function.

Comment: Superfluous cast and `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. But more importantly, `1000` is wrong.

Comment: @ikegami: 1000 is just an example.

Comment: That doesn't matter; no other number is ok either

Comment: I already explained the three errors, including the major one of an incorrect hard-coded number

Comment: besides, [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: I did mention that :)

Answer (score 2):

`char* result[1000];` creates an array of 1000 pointers. That's wrong in a number of ways.

1. You want a block of 1000 chars, not pointers.
2. Actually, 1000 is not the number of characters you want. You usually want a smaller number, but you could also want a larger number.
3. You don't want to store the result in automatically allocated memory, because that will be freed as soon as you exit the function. Use `malloc` (or something that does a `malloc` such as `strdup`).

Fix:

```
// Returns a copy that needs to be freed.
char* find_word_start(const char* src) {
   while (*src == ' ')
      ++src;

   size_t len = 0;
   while (str[len] != '\0')
      ++len;

   ++len;  // Include NUL
   result = malloc(len);

   char* dst = result;
   while (len--)
      *(dst++) = *(src++);

   return result;
}
```

Well, I was avoiding using string functions above like you did, but they greatly simplify the solution.

```
// Returns a copy that needs to be freed.
char* find_word_start(const char* src) {
   while (*src == ' ')
      ++src;

   return strdup(src);
}
```

That said, since you return the tail end of the string, you could simply return a pointer into the existing string.

```
// Returns a pointer into the provided string.
const char* find_word_start(const char* str) {
   while (*str == ' ')
      ++str;

   return str;
}
```